# Java 8 migration - Test planning for low latency applications

Tags: java-8

We are planning for Java 8 migration for our application from Java 7. As part of this migration, the most important thing that we want to achieve is to recompile our source code using JDK 8 and gain out of the performance improvement made in JVM, garbage collection model etc. Besides this, we want to also set stage to take advantage from the new features added in Java 8.

My question to this group is to get some advice on how should we plan our testing. What are the key areas that we should be watching out for? What are some of the challenges that others have faced?

Note: Our application is intended for low latency use.

Comment: It seems to be off topic. Better ask this question in a forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things...

Some things that *compile* under jdk-7 might not with jdk-8. This is because lots of bugs were fixed and some code now potentially might be *much closer* to the `jls` (this is probably more about generics, but might affect other areas as well).

If you have external libraries, not all are compatible with jdk-8.

HashMap internals have changed. If you rely on some iteration order (I've seen that), it might now fail; otherwise the internal changes will only make your `HashMap` usages faster.

You say that your app is intended for `low latency`. Be aware that Stream operations are slower and require more resources then simpler structures. BUT unless you *actually* measure this to be an impact (it wasn't my case when migrating), there's nothing to worry about.

This is a great example where if you have your test cases in place - they would help A LOT. You would be catching all the major problems at that point (if any).

I'd say that the biggest challenge for me was not the migration itself, but the *post-migration*. Lots of people (including me) have done multiple mistakes in basic stuff - since lambda and Streams were quite new. My personal advice here - do not be afraid to ask. Better late then sorry.

P.S. As noted in comment, you should also check [this guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html).